# PHP if else inside select form

Tags: php, if-statement, select

Putting together the simplest of web forms with a select drop down, yet for some reason, this one relentlessly seems to select the ELSE each time the $teamtypeid is equal to 1. I am using a print to ensure $teamtypeid does actually equal 1 and it displays it correctly in that print statement on the live site, yet the select shows option 2 still shows as selected in the drop down each time.

I feel like this must be something incredibly obvious that I am missing, but can't spot it!

```
<label for="select01">Team: <?= print $teamtypeid ?></label>
<select class="form-control" id="select01" name="teamtype">
    <?php
    if($teamtypeid == 1)
        {
        echo"
        <option value=1 SELECTED>First Team 1</option>
        <option value=2>Reserves/Youth</option>
        ";
        }
    else
        {
        echo"
        <option value=1>First Team</option>
        <option value=2 SELECTED>Reserves/Youth</option>
        ";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `$teamtypeid` isn't actually set.

```
<?= print $teamtypeid ?>
// <?= is same as <?php echo
// so its same as
<?php echo print $teamtypeid ?>
// print doesn't print anything because $teamtypeid isn't set
// and echo is echoing the return value (1) of print
```

Right now you are just echoing the return value of print here, which is always 1.

> The major differences to echo are that print only accepts a single argument and always returns 1.
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php

Comment: Very good catch! Yes, this sounds exactly like what the problem is. To the OP, I'd encourage you to always use `<?php` for every opening tag, even if it is convenient to sometimes use the short or echo versions, for this exact reason.